# Как сохранить plt.plot для последующего использования в других функциях?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

передо мной стоит задача:
Создать класс с 3 методами
1 метод genPoints записывает в файл x значения от 0 до 99, в файл y рандомные двузначные значения.
2 метод drawPlot строит график по x и y из файлов.
3 метод scrPlot сохраняет график ввиде картинки.

У меня проблема в связи между методом 2 и 3. Я конечно наговнокодил так, что в методе drawPlot я создаю график и отображаю его, а в scrPlot я делаю тоже самое, но не отображаю, а сохраняю.
Вопрос: как передать график в метод scrPlot, чтобы в методе было мало строк кода (чтобы было что-то на подобие такого plt.savefig('foo.png') без повторного plt.plot и сбора из текстового файла координат)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rand
class GDS_Plot:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def genPoints(self):
        xFile = open("x", "w")
        for i in range(0,100,1):
            xFile.write(str(i))
            xFile.write("\n")
        
        yFile = open("y", "w")
        for i in range(0,100,1):
            yFile.write(str(rand.randint(10, 99)))
            yFile.write("\n")
    
    def drawPlot(self):
        xFile = open("x", "r")
        xVal = xFile.read()
        xVal_list = xVal.split('\n')
        xVal_list.pop();
        xFile.close()
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            xVal_list[i] = int(xVal_list[i])
        # print(xVal_list)

        yFile = open("y", "r")
        yVal = yFile.read()
        yVal_list = yVal.split('\n')
        yVal_list.pop();
        yFile.close()
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            yVal_list[i] = int(yVal_list[i])
        
        plt.plot(xVal_list, yVal_list)
        plt.show()
        
        
    def scrPlot(self):
        xFile = open("x", "r")
        xVal = xFile.read()
        xVal_list = xVal.split('\n')
        xVal_list.pop();
        xFile.close()
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            xVal_list[i] = int(xVal_list[i])
        # print(xVal_list)

        yFile = open("y", "r")
        yVal = yFile.read()
        yVal_list = yVal.split('\n')
        yVal_list.pop();
        yFile.close()
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            yVal_list[i] = int(yVal_list[i])
        # print(yVal_list)
        
        plt.plot(xVal_list, yVal_list)
        plt.savefig('foo.png')


        

Plot = GDS_Plot()
Plot.genPoints()
Plot.drawPlot()
Plot.scrPlot()
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rand


class GDS_Plot:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def genPoints(self):
        xFile = open("x", "w")
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            xFile.write(str(i))
            xFile.write("\n")
        
        yFile = open("y", "w")
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            yFile.write(str(rand.randint(10, 99)))
            yFile.write("\n")
    
    def drawPlot(self):
        xFile = open("x", "r")
        xVal = xFile.read()
        xVal_list = xVal.split('\n')
        xVal_list.pop();
        xFile.close()
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            xVal_list[i] = int(xVal_list[i])

        yFile = open("y", "r")
        yVal = yFile.read()
        yVal_list = yVal.split('\n')
        yVal_list.pop();
        yFile.close()
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            yVal_list[i] = int(yVal_list[i])
        
        self._plt = plt.plot(xVal_list, yVal_list)
        plt.show()
        
        return xVal_list, yVal_list                             # +++
        
    def scrPlot(self, xVal_list, yVal_list):                    # +++
        plt.plot(xVal_list, yVal_list)
        plt.savefig('foo.png')
        

Plot = GDS_Plot()
Plot.genPoints()

xVal_list, yVal_list = Plot.drawPlot()                          # +++

Plot.scrPlot(xVal_list, yVal_list)                              # +++
```

Comment: Спасибо, я придумал иначе. Я в методе drawPlot возвращаю fig, которая равна plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))<br>
В основной части кода<br>
fig = Plot.drawPlot()<br>
Plot.scrPlot(fig)<br>